# Prove a set is countable using its intersections

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing, set-theory

I have the following question:

Suppose $A$ is a collection of subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ such that the intersection of any $b$ of them is a subset of $\{k \in \mathbb{N} : k < b\}$. Prove that $A$ is countable.

My initial thought was that since $\mathbb{N}$ is countable then any collection of subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ is likewise countable. But that would be incorrect since the power set of $\mathbb{N}$ is not countable by Cantor's Theorem. So instead to prove that $F$ is countable, I'm thinking for this question I need to create a bijection from $\mathbb{N}$ to $F$ but unsure how to do so using the intersection of any $m$ of them is a subset of $\{k \in \mathbb{N} : k < b\}$. I want to say that $\{k \in \mathbb{N} : k < b\}$ is countable since it's a subset of $\mathbb{N}$. But then I'm not sure how to relate that back to $A$.

The other approach I was thinking of was to say something like, let's define $m$ sufficiently large so that it has the same magnitude as $A$ but that assumption fails too because that will assume $A$ to be countable from the beginning.

Any advice or hints about this problem would be much appreciated

Comment: So you mean that the intersection of any $1$ of those subsets is a subset of $\{k\in\mathbb N : k<1\} = \emptyset$?

Comment: That's how the question is written in the review questions I have: The intersection of any  of them is a subset of {∈ℕ:<}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would assume $b$ is a fixed natural number, so we cannot choose it.
Under that assumption, the following works as a proof:

Define $[b] := \{k \in \mathbb{N} \mid k < b\}$.  Now, given any subset $X \subseteq \mathbb{N}$, it holds that either $X \subseteq [b]$ or there is some [likely not at all unique] natural number $n \geq b$ such that $n \in X$.  In particular, this means we may write
$$\mathcal{A} = \{A \in \mathcal{A} \mid A \subseteq [b]\} \cup \bigcup_{n \geq b} \{A \in \mathcal{A} \mid n \in A\}.$$

The set $\{A \in \mathcal{A} \mid A \subseteq [b]\}$ is a subset of the power set of $[b]$, which is finite, and therefore $\{A \in \mathcal{A} \mid A \subseteq [b]\}$ is finite.  Additionally, the union is indexed over natural numbers $n \geq b$, so it is a countable union, so the only question is how large each set in the union can be.

To this end, fix $n \geq b$ and consider $\{A \in \mathcal{A} \mid n \in A\}$.  If this set has at least $b$ elements, we can select $b$ of them $A_1, A_2, \ldots, A_b$, but then $n \in \bigcap_{i=1}^b A_i \subseteq [b]$ is a contradiction as $n \not\in [b]$.  It follows that $\{A \in \mathcal{A} \mid n \in A\}$ has at most $b-1$ elements, so in particular, it's a finite collection of sets.

It follows that $\mathcal{A}$ is a countable union of finite sets, hence it is countable.

---

*The following was my initial proof, which is much less elegant by my judgement.  I'm leaving it here just to highlight another way you might work such a problem.*

First, we show that if $\mathcal{A}_0$ is a collection of subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ such that the intersection of any $b$ of them is empty, then $\mathcal{A}_0$ is countable.

To prove this claim, first we reconsider what "the intersection of any $b$ of them is empty" means in terms of the elements of $\mathbb{N}$.  That is, the intersection of any $b$ sets in $\mathcal{A}_0$ will be empty precisely when each element $n \in \mathbb{N}$ lies in **at most** $b-1$ sets in $\mathcal{A}_0$.  If we think about it, this gives us a way of listing out all the elements of $\mathcal{A}_0$!

- Step -1: If $\emptyset \in \mathcal{A}_0$, then put it first.
- Step 0: Choose an order for the at most $b-1$ sets $C \in \mathcal{A}_0$ such that $0 \in C$. Add them to the list in this order.
- Step 1: Choose an order for the at most $b-1$ sets $C \in \mathcal{A}_0$ such that $1 \in C$. Add them to the list in this order.
- ...
- Step n: Choose an order for the at most $b-1$ sets $C \in \mathcal{A}_0$ such that $n \in C$.  Add them to the list in this order.

This list represents a surjection $\mathbb{N} \to \mathcal{A}_0$, so $\mathcal{A}_0$ will be countable.

---

Now we turn to the original problem of whether $\mathcal{A}$ is countable.  For this, we consider the map $$\Psi : \mathcal{A} \to \mathcal{P}(\{b, b+1, b+2, \ldots\})$$
defined by
$$\Psi(C) = C\cap \{b, b+1, b+2, \ldots\}.$$

Then the range of $\Psi$ is a collection $\Psi(\mathcal{A})$ of subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ such that the intersection of any $b$ of them is empty.  By the above argument, $\Psi(\mathcal{A})$ is countable.

Now, $\mathcal{P}(\{0, 1, \ldots, b-1\})$ is the power set of a finite set, hence finite, and since the cartesian product of a finite set and a countable set is countable, we see that $\mathcal{P}(\{0,1,\ldots,b-1\}) \times \Psi(\mathcal{A})$ is countable.  Therefore, the map
$$\Phi : \mathcal{P}(\{0,1,\ldots, b-1\}) \times \Psi(\mathcal{A}) \to \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$$
defined by the union $\Phi(C_1, C_2) = C_1 \cup C_2$ has a countable range!

Why is that a good result?  It's because $$\mathcal{A} \subset \Phi(\mathcal{P}(\{0,1,\ldots, b-1\}) \times \Psi(\mathcal{A})),$$
so we conclude $\mathcal{A}$ is countable since it's a subset of a countable set.

*The proof of this last claim, that $\mathcal{A}$ is a subset of that countable set we constructed, is simple if you have been able to follow the arguments up to that point, so I'll leave it to the reader.*

Answer (score 3):

So for this problem I am going to assume that $b \gt 1$ as if $b=1$ the problem breaks down as the intersection is a binary set operator. I am also assuming that $\mathbb{N}/0$ and that all elements in sets in $A$ are in $\mathbb{N}$. Hopefully my reasons for doing so are clear.

Hint: Start by proving that no set in A can contain members of the other sets in a other than $1$.

My Solution:
Let $b = 2$ then $\forall r_{1}, r_{2} \in A$   $r_{1} \cap r_{2} = \emptyset$ or $\{1\}$  Therefore any two sets in $A$ must not share any elements other than $\{1\}$. We know that $A$ can vary in elements, but by our condition we can show that one formulation of $A$ is $A_{0} =\{\{x_{n}\}\}$ $\forall x_{n} \in \mathbb{N}$. Now all we have to prove is that this formulation of A is countable and that $\vert A_{0}\vert \ge \vert A\vert$. The first is done by defining the bijection $f:A\to \mathbb{N}$ $st. f(\{x_{n}\}) = x_{n}$ $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$. The second can be shown by noting that, because two sets in A must not share any elements other than $\{1\}$, and if a set contains one and another element the set with that element excluding $1$ cannot be in $A$. So the formulation of $A$ with each set only containing one element or that element and $1$ must have the greatest possible cardinality, assuming each contain all elements in $\mathbb{N}$. Therefore all formulations of $A$ are countable.

Comment: +1. In other words the family $B=\{x\setminus \{1\}: x\in A\}$ is a pairwise-disjoint family of subsets of $\Bbb N,$ so $B$ is countable. And $A\subseteq B\cup \{y\cup \{1\}:y\in B\}.$